# Replace content regex - Perl (multiline)

Tags: regex, perl, replace

how can i replace this value only when i catch Name = "Mario Rossi"?

i need to replace 94 with 98 only for

```
<PMRQ:Name>John Smith</PMRQ:Name>
<PMRQ:PmtId>                                                                    
<PMRQ:InstrId>95</PMRQ:InstrId>                                                 
<PMRQ:EndToEndId>45700100523011712061901541</PMRQ:EndToEndId>                   
</PMRQ:PmtId> 

<PMRQ:Name>Mario Rossi</PMRQ:Name>
<PMRQ:PmtId>                                                                    
<PMRQ:InstrId>94</PMRQ:InstrId>                                                 
<PMRQ:EndToEndId>45700100522011712061901541</PMRQ:EndToEndId>                  
</PMRQ:PmtId>
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Where is your attempt? What have you explored?

Comment: Since this is an XML structure, I would recommend looking at an XML solution rather than a Perl solution.

Comment: i want replace
<PMRQ:InstrId>94</PMRQ:InstrId>
but only when <PMRQ:InstrId> is found after match "Mario Rossi"

Answer (score 1):

For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) you can write

```
open file.xml ;
for //PMRQ:Name[.="Mario Rossi"]
    set following-sibling::PMRQ:PmtId[1]/PMRQ:InstrId 98 ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Good answer, but he is asking for help with Perl.

Comment: @EduardoLynchAraya: `xsh` is written in Perl, it's a wrapper around its [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) library. You can include this code into your Perl script as a parameter to the `xsh` function.

Comment: i need a into perl script, have you any idea?

Comment: @Mariano: Yes, install [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), put `xsh '...'` around my code, and that's it.

Comment: thanks if i need to replace PMRQ:InstrId with <PMRQ:Amt Ccy="VAL">

Comment: Use `set .../PMRQ:Amt/@Ccy value` to set an attribute value.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qx6GNqtQ
this is the real XML, which is the code that i can replace 1529.27 only after Mario Rossi? Really thanks Choroba

Answer (score 0):

This works, no extra modules required.

Assume $text contains the multiline data you want to modify. Then just do:

```
$text=~s/<PMRQ:Name>Mario Rossi<\/PMRQ:Name>\s*<PMRQ:PmtId>\s*<PMRQ:InstrId>\K\d+/98/msg;
```

The 'g' (global) modifier at the end is needed to perform multiple matches (but does not hurt if you have zero or one matches).